# windows.forms.webbrowser - Unable to load Client Print Control SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, printing, webbrowser-control

I know this is a common issue but I've been unable to resolve looking at similar posts.
I have a windows application that embeds SSRS in a windows.forms.webbrowser control.  From my dev and test environment I can print reports no problem.
I have a client using my applicatin and they can print reports when viewing SSRS in Internet Explorer, however when they try and print from within my application they receive the error message 'Unable To Load Client Print Control'.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why printing reports in IE would be fine, whilst printing from a windows.forms.webbrowser is not?

Clients are using Internet Explorer 9, SSRS 2012

Please let me konw if you need more info.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Windows.Forms.Webbrowser was using IE 64-bit.  I installed the 64bit client print control for ssrs and printing works.
This was confusing as IE 64-bit was not the default browser.  although my applications platform target is designed for both 32 and 64 bit, it was using 64bit IE.
Hopefully this can help others.